# Loading UIWebView From Background Fetch

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift

I am using a UIWebView in my app to load the contents of a website. I then use javascript to log into the website, and then I parse the contents of the page after I've logged in to grab the data I need. I do this every 5 minutes, which works fine in the foreground. However, when I background the app, I make a call to the UIViewController that holds the UIWebView and I hit the method that loads the URL into the UIWebView, but nothing happens after that.

I am fairly sure that the UIViewController must be active to update the UIWebView, but is there a way around this? Checking this data in the background is really the entire point of the app.

EDIT

jakepeterson - Based on your code, I tried to subclass a UIWebView starting in Swift. This is as far as I got:

```
    class CustomWebView: UIWebView, UIWebViewDelegate
{
    var webView: UIWebView
    var requestURL: NSURL
    var urlRequest: NSURLRequest

    init()
    {
        webView = UIWebView()
        requestURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
        urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)

        super.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.addSubview(webView.window)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(sender: UIWebViewDelegate)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

I am still not hitting the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method. I think it has to do possibly with this line:

webView.addSubview(webView.window)

In your code you have self.view but that doesn't show up as an available option.

**UPDATE**

Here is what I am doing now and the delegates are now getting triggered:

```
import UIKit

class CustomWebView: UIWebView
{
    var uiView = UIView()

    init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    convenience init(frame:CGRect, request:NSURLRequest)
    {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        uiView.addSubview(self)
        loadRequest(request)
    }    
}

extension CustomWebView: UIWebViewDelegate
{
    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView!)
    {
        println("webViewDidStartLoad")
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)
    {
        println("webViewDidFinishLoad")
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView!, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!)
    {
        println("An error occurred while loading the webview")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the trick I found of adding the control to a UIView to get the delegates to fire only works in the foreground. So for anyone checking this question there currently does not seem to be a way to do this in the background.

Comment: is that also true for `WKWebView`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how the `UIWebView` class can be used objectively with asynchronous logic:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
        self.webView.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:self.webView];

        self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        [self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self)
    {
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self.webView loadRequest:request];
        [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    NSLog(@"An error occurred while loading. (error: %@)", error);

    // Alert the user
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:@"Dude... we messed up. This web page can't be loaded at this time." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

**Why does this work?**

Because you are depending on the delegate methods of `UIWebViewDelegate` to tell you when the `UIWebView` has finished loading. I included the error delegate method as a bonus.

The example here is using a `UIActivityIndicatorView` class, which is designed for use in asynchronous tasks. By following this same implementation style, you can replace the `activityIndicator` with virtually anything you plan to act on the results of the `UIWebView` pragmatically with.

Good luck

**UPDATE**

Swift is a whole other beast. Your swift class has a plethora of errors in it. This is how I would re-write what I originally gave you in ObjC in Swift:

```
import UIKit

class CustomWebView: UIWebView {

    var activityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    convenience init(frame:CGRect, request:NSURLRequest) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        loadRequest(request)
    }

}

extension CustomWebView: UIWebViewDelegate {

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView!, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!) {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

        println("An error occurred while loading the webview")
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I edited my original post to explain what I am seeing.

Comment: Thanks for converting that to Swift. It helped me understand what you were doing a bit better. When I run your code though I am unable to set the NSURLRequest. Every time I try to initialize it with one I get an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error on the "self.request = newValue" line.

Comment: I'm extremely new so bear with my while I try and debug. I added the line "println("\(newValue)") to where the NSURLRequest is being set. I get this in the console window: "<NSURLRequest: 0xb30ab40> { URL: http://www.google.com, headers: (null) }". I get this hundreds of times. So I wonder if it gets stuck in a loop and runs out of memory for some reason...

Comment: Ok it no longer crashes, but now I am back to my original issue in that the delegate events never fire, specifically the webViewDidFinishLoad event.

Comment: Are you passing in a non-nil request in your initializer?

Comment: I updated my original question to show what I am using to initialize the control.

Comment: Ok I made the changes that you suggested and the same issue occurs. None of the delegate events get hit. I also tried adding webViewDidStartLoad just for laughs but that does not get hit either.

Comment: Ok I am starting to think that the UIWebViewDelegate events only get triggered when the UIWebView is added to a parent control. I updated my code above, and now my delegates are getting hit. Can you tell me if there is anything wrong with my code or any reason that doing it this way may cause issues?